# Angular 5 - components - cmd prompt - not visible in IDE

Tags: angular, ide, webstorm

For Angular 5, I am using WebStorm IDE. I also installed Angular CLI & Node.js. local host was executed successfully. Now, I have created a component folder in command prompt using `ng generate component about` and they were created successfully. But they are not visible in IDE?

here "about" is the "folder name".

I knew the process of creating the component folder in IDE.

Comment: think you have executed command in wrong project folder

Comment: try refreshing WebStorm VFS (`File | Synchronize`) - can you see the generated files? BTW, you can create new components in IDE using `New | Angular CLI...` right-click menu action